# How to use several next.js plugins (typescript and stylus)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, stylus, next.js

I try to build next.js project with typescript and stylus using [next-compose-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-compose-plugins).

My next.config.js:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript')
const withStylus = require('@zeit/next-stylus')

module.exports = withPlugins([

  [withTypescript, {
    webpack(config, options) {
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty',
      }

      return config
    },
    typescriptLoaderOptions: {
      transpileOnly: false,
    }
  }],

  [withStylus, {
    cssModules: true,
  }],

])
```

In my `button.tsx` I'm importing stylus file:

```
import styles from './button.styl'
console.log(styles) // undefined
```

button.styl contains class names I'd like to use in my components but instead getting `undefined`.

I've added `declare module '*.styl'` to my `externals.d.ts` and included it in `include` section of `tsconfig.json`

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:** getting same issue for `@zeit/next-css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zeit/next-typescript 1.0.0 is released 3 days ago, and raise error with typescriptLoaderOptions:

```
Error: `typescriptLoaderOptions` in next.config.js is no longer supported. https://err.sh/next-plugins/typescript-loader-options
    at module.exports (/Users/set0gut1/tmp/stackoverflow/nextjs/node_modules/@zeit/next-typescript/index.js:15:11)
```

With this version, I could import stylus file.

- next.config.js: delete `typescriptLoaderOptions` from yours.
- I do not make externals.d.ts
- index.tsx:

---

```
import styles from './button.styl'
console.log(styles) // { 'button-class-name': '_1U60cMSmedjISleJqYp7tU' }

export default () => {
    return <div>test</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`next-recompose-plugins`](https://github.com/IdkMan2/next-recompose-plugins) to get clear information which plugin is causing the error.