# Next JS config multiple plugin configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, apollo

```js
const {
  DEVELOPMENT_SERVER,
  PRODUCTION_BUILD
} = require("next/constants");

require('dotenv').config()

const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

const nextConfig = {
  webpack: config => ({ ...config, node: { fs: "empty" } })
};
module.exports = phase => {
  if (phase === DEVELOPMENT_SERVER || phase === PRODUCTION_BUILD) {
    const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
    return withCSS(nextConfig);
  }
  return nextConfig;
};
*module.exports =  {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || []
    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,
      // Read the .env file
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
        systemvars: true
      })
    ]
    return config
  }
}*

let prefix;
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case "test":
    prefix = "https://test.domain.com/providers";
    break;
  case "stage":
    prefix = "https://state.domain.com/providers";
    break;
  case "production":
    prefix = "https://production.domain.com/providers";
    break;
  default:
    prefix = "";
    break;
}
module.exports = {
  distDir: "build",
  assetPrefix: prefix
};
```

Here my next.config.js configuration.
But when I am trying to run then getting the message like 
Error! Network error: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

But when I am trying to run whatever into the bold(*) and kept only that thing into the next.config.js then working fine.
How to configure multiple plugin into the module.export

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/7 - or maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50294005/how-to-use-several-next-js-plugins-typescript-and-stylus

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple way to use multiple nested plugins in Next.js

```
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCSS(withImages({
    webpack(config, options) {
      return config
    }
  }))
```

If you want to using single one plugin then do this:

```
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.export = withImages();
```

For further information about Next.js plugins and their documentation click here:
https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages

Answer (score 9):

`next-compose-plugins` plugin provides a cleaner API for enabling and configuring plugins for next.js.

Install `npm install --save next-compose-plugins`

Use it in `next.config.js`:

```
// next.config.js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const images = require('next-images');
const sass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const typescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript');

// optional next.js configuration
const nextConfig = {
  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,
  distDir: 'build',
};

module.exports = withPlugins([

  // add a plugin with specific configuration
  [sass, {
    cssModules: true,
    cssLoaderOptions: {
      localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    },
  }],

  // add a plugin without a configuration
  images,

  // another plugin with a configuration
  [typescript, {
    typescriptLoaderOptions: {
      transpileOnly: false,
    },
  }],

], nextConfig);
```

Answer (score 4):

Next.js version >10.0.3

Images are now built-in, so to add plugin and image code below will work:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        domains: ['sd.domain.com'], // your domain
    },
};

module.exports = withPlugins([
    [withCSS]
], nextConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```js
    // next.config.js
    const withLess = require("next-with-less");
    const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
    
    const pwa = withPWA({
      pwa: {
        dest: 'public'
      }
    })
    
    module.exports = withLess({
      lessLoaderOptions: {
    
      },
      reactStrictMode: true,
      typescript: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
      },
      eslint: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
      }, 
      ...pwa // using spread to merge the objects
    });
```