# NextJS, Storybook, SVG and absolute import paths

Tags: typescript, next.js, storybook

Can't use SVG as modules for both NextJS app and Storybook, imported with absolute paths. With many tried setups I was able to import SVG either in Next or in Storybook, but not both. I used this setup for `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg`:

```
// .babelrc
{
  ...
  "plugins": [
    ...
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

With this plugin Storybook doesn't require any configuration and this example code works as expected:

```
import Wrapper from '../../../components/Wrapper';
import IconSVG from '../../../icons/sandwich.svg';

export const WrappedSVG = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    <IconSVG />
  </Wrapper>
);
```

But the following does not:

```
import Wrapper from 'components/Wrapper';
import IconSVG from 'icons/sandwich.svg';

export const WrappedSVG = () => (
  <Wrapper>
    <IconSVG />
  </Wrapper>
);
```

Wrapper is being processed, but not the icon: `Cannot find module`

Here is `svgr` setup:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    ...
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

```
// .storybook/main.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    ...
    config.module.rules.unshift({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
}
```

This configuration works fine on the app side, but in Storybook I get `DOMException: "String contains an invalid character"`

My `npm run dev` script is this: `ts-node --project tsconfig.server.json src/server.ts` (via `nodemon`).

I hope somebody would give me a hint how to make absolute import of SVG components work for both NextJS and Storybook.

Answer (score 6):

There's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54292667/945370) to a different problem that worked for me here.

It might be because a conflict with Storybook's default SVG loader. Here's what worked for me:

```
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    const rules = config.module.rules;
    const fileLoaderRule = rules.find(rule => rule.test.test('.svg'));
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/;

    rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```

Comment: This sort of works, but the import ts error is still there

Comment: This worked for me, after trying many other resolves. Thank-you @Brendan :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding absolute paths, Next.js now supports the aliases in file imports with minimal custom configuration in tsconfig.json/jsconfig.json files (No need for webpack configuration  (*experimental stage)).

To configure, have a look [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/11293)!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by configuration webpack. Create the next.config.js file, at the project root, it it doesn't exists, and add this:

```
//next.config.js

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias['~'] = path.resolve(__dirname);
    return config;
  }
};
```

How to use:

```
import myimage from '~/somepath/myimage.svg'
```

More details at this nice [tutorial](https://remysharp.com/2019/11/04/nice-imports-with-nextjs).

Check Weppack documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/).

For multiple plugin configuration at next.config.js check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354512/2700303).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work with a similar setup.

You want to install and add the [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) into `.babelrc` like this where root is the root of the absolute path you want to start from.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."]
    }],
    ...
  ]
}
```

The problem is Babel runs before Webpack so even though you setup the rules it won't work because svgs are processed by Babel.

Then I installed this [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) which bring the `baseUrl` and `paths` from `tsconfig.json`.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: config => {
    config.resolve.plugins = [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()]
    
    return config;
  }
};
```

Now you should be able to import svgs like this:

```
// components/myComponent/myDeepComponent.tsx
import Icon from "assets/icons/icon.svg"
```

The trick is you have to understand is that Babel runs long before Webpack. You can read more in [this github thread](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg/issues/87) which made me realise the issue.